# How do i use should_receive with [] on hashes?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

I want to test that the `tags` object receives the method `[:artist]`.

```
def artist
  @tagger.tags(@mp3)[:artist]
end
```

I'm trying something like this.

```
tagger = double("tagger")
tags.tagger = tagger
tagger.stub(:tags) { Hash.new }
tagger.tags.stub(:[])

tagger.should_receive(:tags).with(mp3)
tagger.tags.should_receive('[:artist]')

tags.artist
```

This causes a syntax error because rspec tries to create a method like:

```
def [:artist]
```

which is not valid syntax.

Is there a valid way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this but I seem to recall doing something like this:

```
tagger.tags.should_receive(:[]).with(:artist)
```

Hope this helps

Edit: Just checked it out and I can confirm this is valid.